# Mule Salesforce Connector TLS 1.1 upgrade Issue

Tags: salesforce, mule

I was working on one poc which will connect to salesforce account . The mule version is 6.3.2 and sales force version is 6.3.2. Till 2 [![enter image description here][1]][1]days back it was working fine.

I came to know that last weekend sales force as done TLS upgrade to 1.1 from 1.0. When i was  testing my flow getting the below exception:

**Root Exception stack trace:
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT'
 exceptionMessage='TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.'
]
]**

When i saw the mule documentation it says that sales force connector 7.1.2 as addressed this issue and I update my connector in studio and retried the scenario which is not working.

Can some one help me out on this.

Regards
Vikram

Comment: What version of Anypoint Studio and Mule Runtime are you using (you wrote "6.3.2" which is not a valid one)? Are you using API Gateay as well? If yes, what version?

Comment: Recently I faced this issue. Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38107239/6521128

Answer (score 0):

I previously had to set the following property in the application settings:

https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

And -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2  in my wrapper.conf for Mule standalone.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the comment. In your answer application settings where exactly it has to be mentioned . Is it in mule flow or studio level ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your configuration in `tls-default.conf` in `MULE_ESB/conf/` folder
and then put the value inside like below:

```
enabledProtocols=TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
enabledCipherSuites=TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
```

Or if you want to test from your anypoint studio, just create the tls-default.conf and put under your `resources` folder

Another information I can add is try to input your url destination to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to make sure the TLSv1.1 is enabled by your endpoint or the chiper suite enable too

Comment: Hi Han , Thanks for the comment. By default my MMC as enabled with "enabledProtocols=TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2" . Can you confirm by enabling CipherSuites if will it impact any where?.  Currently I am using jdk 1.7 , by upgrading it 1.8 resolves it ?

Comment: and one more point is , my flow is having http as inbound not the https!! .

Answer (score 0):

Similar is answered in https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/41012/getting-error-when-hitting-a-rest-api-via-https.html#answer-43960

Below is the answer I posted.

> I resolved it in my system.
>
> When it is not working in the Runtime that is attached in the Anypoint
>   studio then follow the below steps.
>
> ```
> Navigate to the Anypoint studio installation directory
>
> Search for "tls-default.conf" in the folder. This will show you all the files for all the Runtimes that you have installed.
>
> there will be a property "enabledProtocols" make sure that it contains the TLSv1 in it as below
>
> enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
> ```
>
> This above should apply to Cloud hub (Most of the times it is already
>   enabled) or on-premise systems.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce are now [disabling TLS 1.0, forcing TLS 1.1 or higher](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207).
For Java versions >= 1.8 this is not a problem, but for earlier releases you will want to set the `SSLContext`. This solution worked for me:

```
if (Double.parseDouble(Runtime.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion()) <= 1.7) // Java versions > 1.7 are compatible with TLS 1.1 or higher by default - we want TLSv1.2 for our needs
    setSSLContext(SSLContext.getInstance(SSL_VERSION_TO_USE_FOR_SALESFORCE_LOGIN));

private static void setSSLContext(SSLContext context) {
    SSLContext.setDefault(context);
    try {
        /*  Either of the first two parameters may be null in which case the installed security providers will be searched for the highest priority implementation of the appropriate factory.
             Likewise, the secure random parameter may be null in which case the default implementation will be used. */
        context.init(null, null, null);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to Setup
- In the Quick Find bar, type in Critical Updates
- Select Critical Updates
- Locate the Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections​ under the Update Name column
- Click on Deactivate.

[image]